# Get the top line from a Shapely polygon

Tags: python, python-3.x, shapely

From a Shapely polygon, how can the top be obtained as a line? A line that describes the projection from above.

Let's assume the following Polygon:

```py
Polygon([
    [3, 2],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 4],
    [4, 3],
    [8, 3],
    [7, 4],
    [9, 4],
    [8, 1],
])
```

In this case the "projection" from above, or what a top viewer would see is described by:

```py
[
    (2,3),
    (4,4),
    (4,3),
    (7,3),
    (7,4),
    (9,4),
]
```

This is the dashed red line in the following plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from shapely import Polygon

p = Polygon([
    [3, 2],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 4],
    [4, 3],
    [8, 3],
    [7, 4],
    [9, 4],
    [8, 1],
])

y_min = p.bounds[1]
container = Polygon()
for (c1, c2) in zip(p.exterior.coords[:-1], p.exterior.coords[1:]):
    container = Polygon([c1, c2, (c2[0], y_min), (c1[0], y_min), c1]).union(container)
    
top_line = LineString([x for x in container.exterior.coords if x[1] > y_min])
```